# Didreceivenotification never gets called although i receive the notification

Tags: ios, push-notification

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
     didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo ;
```

and

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:
                    (NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult 
                     result))completionHandler{};
```

never get called ,although i receive the notification on the iphone, Is there any other function that needs to be added for this to work?.Thank you.

**Update** 
I tried this when the app is not in background nor active but i didnt receive the message.
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Set app's client ID for |GPPSignIn| and |GPPShare|.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
 registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

// Clear application badge when app launches
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
if ([[launchOptions allKeys] containsObject:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) {

    id userInfo=[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"MESSAGE" message:userInfo delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: This method call when application is active or backgroud,if you application close then this method never call.

Comment: so is there any function that i can implement to receive push notification if the app is not in background nor active?

Comment: yes,in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions..

Comment: Please make sure, Is your application in the background or foreground? If it's in the foreground, I'm sure that method is called. If it isn't, maybe you aren't putting that method in your application delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your application close and get notification .....

add below code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
if ([[launchOptions allKeys] containsObject:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) 
{    
    id userInfo=[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]);
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"MESSAGE" message:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

but this call when you click on notification

Comment: i tried it but it didnt work , please check my updated question

Comment: have you try with terminate state... means application is close

Comment: Thank you Nitin, yes it worked but the problem now , that when i click the push notification, it opens the screen and in less than a second it dismisses it again, don't know why!

Comment: UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"MESSAGE" message:userInfo delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show]; remove this

Comment: I dont know how to print it in NSLOG , as if i removed the app from background ,it will be no longer be attached to Xcode :( thats why i used the alertview , any ideas how?